# Is it possible to download a file from AWS S3 bucket using postman?

Tags: amazon-s3, postman

Using Postman scripting, how to download the file from AWS S3 bucket

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible,
Because in the browser download it's not just a direct 1 **chunk** 
so it's creating a **synchronous [stream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API) job** which load chunk after another and such a system is not supported by `postman`